# Conditional Distribution of the Normal Probability Distribution Function

Tags: regression, probability, normal-distribution, sampling, simulation

I am trying to better understand the conditional distribution of the normal probability distribution function:

https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat505/lesson/6/6.1

"Any distribution for a subset of variables from a multivariate normal, conditional on known values for another subset of variables, is a multivariate normal distribution."

Suppose I have data corresponding to 3 variables : Var_1 , Var_2 and Var_3. I am interested in predicting Var_3 using Var_1 and Var_2.

Suppose I  fit a multivariate normal distribution to this data - doesn't the multivariate normal distribution have special properties such that the conditional distribution of any of the variables within the multivariate normal distribution will also form a normal distribution? Suppose I want to predict the value of Var_3 when Var_1 = a AND Var_2 = b.

Couldn't I just "fix" the values of the other two variables and construct a conditional distribution for the response variable Prob (Var_3 |  Var_1 = a and Var_2 = b) ?  Shouldn't "Prob (Var_3 |  Var_1 = a and Var_2 = b) " have a normal distribution? Could I not then generate a distribution (e.g. histogram) of acceptable values of this response variable given the "fixed" values of the other two variables? I think I should be able to sample from Prob (Var_3 |  Var_1 = a and Var_2 = b) given that I have chosen a multivariate normal distribution? Then, I could take the Expected Value of " Prob (Var_3 |  Var_1 = a and Var_2 = b) " to answer my question? E.g when "Var_1 = a and Var_2 = b", Var_3 is most likely to be equal to "c"?

[image]

Would this be considered a "generative model"? Is this a correct strategy in general? Does it make mathematical sense?

Note: I know that I could just fit a regular regression model to this problem, but I am trying to better understand how probability distribution functions work.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to use "marginal distribution" where you ought to mean *conditional* distribution.  If the distinction is unclear, consult the definitions.

Comment: Thank you - you are correct, this is the conditional distribution!